# how can i pass a powershell variable to terraform

Tags: powershell, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

I need to pass a powershell/devops variable to terraform, is there a way of doing this? As in the below example i want the below PR number to be used as a variable in terraform.

testvalue-$(System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to define a variable by the output of a command (shell ..), but you can take a look at this data source [external data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) ,

the idea is that you define a bash script or any program and use it's output as parameters for other resources.

**Example**

```
data "external" "PullRequest" {
  program = [
    "${path.module}/scriptWhichReturnsPullRequestName.sh",
  ]
  result {

  }
}

...
resource ...  {
  value = data.external.PullRequest.property
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put my variables in a variables.tf and trigger terraform execution from a powershell script. Prior that execution I just replace certain strings in variables.tf.